# Get user that belongs to a specific role in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have following table for roles:

```
id |  name      |    user_id

1    Admin            NULL
2    Accountant       1
3    Storekeeper      1
```

and user table like this:

```
id | name    | role_id  

1     Admin      1
2     xyz        2
3     xyz        3
```

I want to retrieve all data from users table that have been created by Admin in my case that have user_id 1.

I'm using this relation:

```
 public function Role()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Role', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

$users = User::with('Role')->whereHas('Role', function($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', 1);
        })->get();
```

but this is not returning data from users table it is returning rows from roles table only that have user_id 1.

larar

Answer (score 0):

From your database structure, the relation user to role is belongsTo not hasMany

- each user has one role.
- each role can be assigned to many users.

User ==Belongs to==> Role

Role ==Has many==> User

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role', 'role_id', 'id');
}
```

And then you call the users with admin role like this.

```
$adminsWithRole = User::with('role')->whereHas('Role', function($query) {
    $query->where('roles.id', 1);
})->get();
```

**Lets say you want to get the Created roles by the users that are admin**

This needs its own relation

```
public function createdRoles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Role', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

The get the created roles by all users that have the role `admin`

```
$adminsWithCreatedRoles = User::with('createdRoles')->whereHas('Role', function($query) {
    $query->where('roles.id', 1);
})->get();
```

Comment: No user_id column in role table is used for storing the id of user who created the role and other users, the query i have used in my question is fetching all the roles that are being created by the parent user i.e. in this case admin, but i want to fetch those roles details from user table also.

Comment: @user3653474 maybe this is what you are after ?